# Mailer Error: SMTP Error: data not accepted

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I want to send mail through PHP, so i am using PHPMailer. Don't know why i am getting this error.

> Mailer Error: SMTP Error: data not accepted.SMTP server error: DATA END command failed Detail: Relaying not allowed - sender domain not local SMTP code: 530

This is my code.

```
require '../library/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP();
//From email address and name
$mail->From = "my@email.address";
$mail->FromName = "Full Name";

//To address and name
$mail->addAddress("my@email.address", "Recipient Name");
//$mail->addAddress("recepient1@example.com"); //Recipient name is     optional

//Address to which recipient will reply
$mail->addReplyTo("p.archish@live.com", "Reply");



//Send HTML or Plain Text email
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
//$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
 {
   echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}
```

Any help or suggestion? and i am not executing this code on local, it's on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unusual for a server to allow sending without authentication. I suggest setting the Host, SMTPAuth, Username and Password properties, as the examples provided with PHPMailer show.