# PHPMailer SMTP: Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Data not accepted

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am unable to send the mail even using SMTP.A few days ago the same code was working fine.

I am getting the below message

> SMTP -> ERROR: DATA not accepted from server: 552 Nz4mckYiQgZ8h ::
>   auth :: Message rejected for spam or virus content :: Please include
>   this entire message when contacting support :: v=2.1 cv=S5F5uNYP c=1
>   sm=1 tr=0 p=DNfEhoIXAAAA:8 a=dRZi5ZaG1PHMBT+NcrGb8g==:117
>   a=L9H7d07YOLsA:10 a=9cW_t1CCXrUA:10 a=s5jvgZ67dGcA:10
>   a=8nJEP1OIZ-IA:10 a=cDqdM3_RAAAA:20 a=pGLkceISAAAA:8
>   a=Fipbmfv_9jaJWARIFGEA:9 a=AJk-FuyA79Q3bGqj:21 a=wPNLvfGTeEIA:10
>   a=93v7MKg8FR1F7PZvwgsN:22 a=6kGIvZw6iX1k4Y-7sg4_:22 :: 100.00
>
> SMTP -> ERROR: RSET failed:  Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Data not
>   accepted.

```
<?php
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "contactus@vowsforeternity.com";
    $mail->Password = "xxxxxxx";
    $mail->AddReplyTo('contactus@vowsforeternity.com');
    $mail->From = "contactus@vowsforeternity.com";
    $mail->FromName = "contactus@vowsforeternity.com";
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    $msg='HTML';
    $msg=urlencode($msg);
    $mail->Body =$msg;
    $mail->AddCC("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    $mail->AddBCC("xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    $mail->AddAddress("xxxxxxxxxxxx");
     if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
     } else {
        echo "Message has been sent";
     }

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mailer Error: SMTP Error: data not accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37405077/mailer-error-smtp-error-data-not-accepted)

Comment: So what is your question here? The error message is crystal clear: your message has been rejected because it is rated as SPAM.

Comment: So what is the solution? I mean , how do I get rid of this